# How can I promote repeating fields to different SharePoint columns?

Tags: infopath, column

I have seen articles describing how to use repeating fields to create multiple list items, but I am trying to figure out how to use repeating fields to populate separate SP columns. For example:

InfoPath:

Repeating table to enter `textField: Approver`

```
Row / Data
 1  / J. Lennon
 2  / G. Harrison
 3  / P. McCartney
```

SharePoint Library:

```
 Column1  /  Column 2   /   Column 3
J. Lennon / G. Harrison / P. McCartney
```

Thanks very much for any guidance.